# Spring data findByStartDateBetween doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have written a Spring MVC app. Now I try to implement the spring data repository, which has a method to find all the `Deal` objects by date parameter.

I tried just to implement this, just like on the Spring Data site (`findByStartDateBetween`):

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public interface DealRepository extends JpaRepository <Deal, Long> {    
    List<Deal> findByStartDateBetween(Date from, Date to);
```

But it doesn't work. It can't create the `DealRepository` bean.

I also tried to write some custom `@Query`, but that failed too.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: You need to include more of your code that implements the findByStartDateBetween.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this problem. I wrote custom query, important is not forget to use @Param. This is what i got

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DealRepository extends JpaRepository<Deal, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("select d from Deal d where d.createdDate >= :from and d.createdDate <= :to ")
    List<Deal> findByCreatedDateBetween(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);
```

Comment: It isn't that you asked. This is a workaround but not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have @Repository notation which ideally creates the bean at the start of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
List<Deal> findByCreatedDateBetween(Date start, Date end);
```